# Julius Caesar Encryption

Tags: java

*Julius Caesar was using a very simple encoding system, which consists of replacing every letter of a message by a letter placed several ranks after in the alphabetical order. For example, for a shifting of 4, A becomes E, B becomes F, up to Z which becomes D.*

I write in java a program which applies the processing described below.
but the problem is my code change spaces
The spaces will be maintained as they are. They are not object of any encoding but will stay present at their position.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Crypto {

    static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static final int DECALAGE = 4;

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Veuillez entrer une chaine de caracteres : ");
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        // la chaine a coder
        String aCoder = "";
        // la chaine codee
        String chaineCodee = "";
        int pos;

        aCoder = s;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(s != ALPHABET) {
                System.out.println("La chaine a coder est vide.\n");
            }

            pos = ALPHABET.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
            int val = (pos+DECALAGE) % 26;
            char replace = ALPHABET.charAt(val);
            chaineCodee = chaineCodee+replace;

        }

        System.out.format("La chaine initiale etait : '%s'\n", s);

        if (aCoder.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("La chaine a coder est vide.\n");
        } else {
            System.out.format("La chaine a coder est : '%s'\n", aCoder);
            System.out.format("La chaine codee est : '%s'\n", chaineCodee);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Identify space with IF and continue code execution with another char.

Comment: add a space to your `ALPHABET` String?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes:

```
//add if
int val=(pos+DECALAGE)%26;
char replace=ALPHABET.charAt(val);
if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
   chaineCodee=chaineCodee+ ' ';
} else {
   chaineCodee=chaineCodee+replace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you encrypt your input char by char, you have to check for characters, that you want to exclude from encryption. Additionally you might want to use a `StringBuilder` for some better performance:

```
final StringBuilder chaineCodee = new StringBuilder();
```

Change your loop like follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (ALPHABET.indexOf(s.toLower().charAt(i)) == -1) {
        chaineCodee.append(s.charAt(i));  //no encryption, just copy the current character
        continue;
    }

    chaineCodee.append(ALPHABET.charAt((ALPHABET.indexOf(s.toLower().charAt(i)) + DECALAGE) % 26));
}
```